# Negative text-indent causes large link selection on click

Tags: css, seo

So a method I often use to create nice SEO links that use images is the `text-indent: -9999px;` trick. Basically, I create a block-level anchor with a background image. I set its `text-indent` to a large negative number so you don't see it and that's good for SEO. When I click on the link though, the outline of it shoots off the page (i.e. it goes with the really far off text). I've found this only happened in certain cases, **most of the time**:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">SEO text</a>
</div>

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

  div a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(stuff) etc...;
  }
```

The above code will 95% of the time only have the outline when you click the link of just the 100 x 100px area. However, when not defining the dimensions of the parent, it seems to shoot off the page.... I think. But in this one case of mine, it has dimensions on the parent yet still shoots off the page. As a result, I did the `a span { display: none; }` trick but I want to know how I can do it with the `text-indent` trick but fix the outline.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I need another parent or need to set another CSS property?

Comment: +1 - something I've noticed but never gotten around to looking into. Great question.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this without setting `outline:none`? I'm interested in why this only seems to happen sporadically, rather than attempts to make the symptoms go away. There's at least an upvote from me in it!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here is a [great article](http://sonspring.com/journal/removing-dotted-links) for removing that cursed outline in firefox

just adding a link felt very lazy so here, add this into your CSS:

```
a
{
  outline: none;
}
:focus
{
  -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: While making the page completely unusable without a mouse

Comment: It has it's pros and cons because you get no feedback on the screen when tabbing with the keyboard but it does fix the issue. Thanks so much for the info though.

Comment: @David: generally I see this as giving an understanding of how it works, though the first example in the article enables it to still be usable without a mouse, getting rid of the outline isn't all you can do, you can change other style attributes to the element instead, i.e: adding a border, so it is still obvious the element is highlighted, but it doesn't have that ridiculous outline shooting off across your page.

Answer (score 21):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the a tag.

```
div a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This maintains the outline border, but only in the specified coordinates of the element.

Applying `overflow: hidden` on the div or `outline: none` like [Wayne Austin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432902/496830) will completely remove the outline which is a usability issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - because hiding the outline is nonsense. Easy, but nonsense :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Add overflow: hidden on your div a